# Using .Net how can I check which users have resources (files/shares) open on a remote server?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

Using .Net how can I check which users in our domain have resources (files, shares) open on a remote Windows server?

If you have any C# examples I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do that using the WMI class `Win32_ConnectionShare`. [This](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1234690.php) discussion has an answer with a simple C# sample that should get you started.

Edit: Just realised that the [NetFileEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525378%28VS.85%29.aspx) API might be a better solution. If you look at the PInvoke page for it [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetFileEnum.html), you can find a basic C# sample.